# slick asp.net grid components on the cheap

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am starting an asp.net project in VWD2010.
Can anyone recommend a decent grid component, skin, theme, jquery plugin etc that wont break the bank (south african rands wont stretch far in dollar/euros)
This project is being done on a shoestring budget but I still want it to look nice

opensource is fine.
trustware fine also (can repay when the system starts generating revenue)

I am weary to just pick something at random and risk it biting me down the line when it goes into production

Thanks!

Comment: For jQuery have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/159025/66849).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [jquery ui](http://jqueryui.com/) for theming purposes, this will theme your standard asp.net grid as well if you configure it.

Also look at the [free stuff](http://www.telerik.com/freestuff) telerik gives, in particular:

- http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/formdecorator.aspx
- http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc.aspx - This is only for Asp.net MVC

So in short if you don't require any special functionality in the datagrid then just skin it with either the telerik formdecorator or jquery ui. Good grid's unfortunately come at a price with [devexpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Subscriptions/DXperience/asp-features.xml) and [telerik](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx).